# Flash support in Android

Tags: android, flash

I am planning to port a flash player to Android OS. Presently Android is not supporting the Flash. I have looked into GNash, an open source flash player but the problem with this is that it is not supporting the latest version flash files and we can't open the youtube with GNash.

Are there any open source light-weight flash players which can be ported to Android.

EDIT: I have also tried SwfDec but even this one is not playing the videos from youtube.

Any other open source players which can play youtube videos?

Comment: I've heard that Silverlight on Android is more likely to happen in the short term. Just sayin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create flash/swf player in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937669/create-flash-swf-player-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ffmpeg to convert the flv to mp4.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this could be a fun project to hack; however, you'll soon face real competition from Adobe, who are porting their own player as we speak:

http://www.google.se/search?q=flash+android

Just in case you can afford to wait.

Comment: They've been claiming that it "mostly works" or is "almost done" since back before the holidays... wonder if we'll ever see it.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google/OHA member engineers the problem you will have is performance on current device hardware specifically G1s..

My impression is that you will not see flash until the Dalvik VM JIT is finished developmentally...probably not until SDK 3.5 probably..

Answer (score 0):

GNash website states (and my own experience confirms) that GNash actually plays most youtube videos OK. See [GNash wiki.](http://wiki.gnashdev.org/YouTube)

Comment: Problem with GNash is that it depends more on Boost libraries. It takes more time to port Boost to Android.

Answer (score 0):

Now Android has flash support,
maybe this can help: 
http://www.synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications
playing FLV on Android using flash player inside a webview