# Create flash/swf player in Android

Tags: android, flash

I have to create an app to play an swf/flash file, having zoom and mouse pointer functionalities.
I have searched a lot, but I didn't find any sample/code or any clue to build a player.

Does anyone know an API or any way to build  such a player?

Has anybody played an  swf file in android other than with WebView?
I have tried to play swf in WebView but it shows only a square image(blue) in the center, even though I have installed flash player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled plugins for your webview:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState

Comment: Dawason -Thanks, I had enabled plugins for webview, but my device had not required config (of processer) to play flash, and the video I am playing contains Action script 2
Device's basic requirements to play swf/flash -
1. ARMv7 processor with vector FPU, minimum 550MHz, OpenGL ES 2.0, H.264 and AAC HW decoders
2. Android™ 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, or 4.0
3. 256MB of RAM